# How to select all options in Tom-select

Tags: tom-select

I want to be able to select all options or 1 optgroup in select built with TomSelect.

There is no option to select all. I reviewed documentation and could not find any info in github.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem today. You can do this like that to select all options:

```js
    var tomSelect = new TomSelect(...)

    $('#check-all').click(function(event) {
        const allValues = tomSelect.options;
        var valuesToSelect = Object.keys(allValues).map(function(key) {
            return allValues[key].value;
        });
        tomSelect.setValue(valuesToSelect); // Set all values to select them
    });
```

Also this to uncheck all:

```js
    $('#uncheck-all').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        tomSelect.setValue([]); // Set all values to empty to uncheck all
    });
```